# How to manipulate the data type in an object array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

For example,

```
object[][,] names2 = new object[2][,];

person[0] = new object[2,3] {{ "Jack",  44, true }, { "Tum",36, false }};
```

I wanna manipulate each data type that the name should need to be a `string`, the age a `int`, etc.

Comment: Why not use Dictionary? Or Expando https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-7.0#enumerating-and-deleting-members

Comment: Don't be afraid to create new types, with the property names and types that you actually want.

Comment: To add to what @JeremyLakeman said, create a class like `class Person { public string Name {get;set;} public int Age {get;set;} public bool IsSmart {get;set;} }`. Then you can create a collection like `List<Person> People = new List<Person> { new Person { Name="Jack", Age=44, IsSmart=true}, new Person { _etc_ }, ...};` Once you get comfortable in C#, you'll find you don't use arrays very often, and never like you show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples).

```
List<(string name, int age, bool idk)> names = new(){( "Jack",  44, true ),("Tum",36, false) };
// I am assuming that persons is of type List<(string name, int age, bool idk)>.
persons = names;
persons[0].name = "John"; // Jack became John

person[0].age = 60; // 44 became 60
```

The above is the simplest way of doing what you want. However, I would recommend following "Flydog57" advice. Just create a class for this and save yourself the headache of dealing with type mismatch, boxing and unboxing, and etc.

One of the big strengths of compiled languages are their strong type systems, I recommend you lean into them not away from them.

Answer (score 2):

```
You can just iterate over array and change accordingly.
Like:
person[0][1]="newPerson";
```